# Does the Eee Box EB1012 support a resolution of 960 by 540?

Tags: resolution, display, eee-pc

The title pretty much says it all. I'm talking about the *display* resolution here, not about video playback.

EDIT: Did anyone actually try this? I was kinda looking for first-hand experience here...

About the bounty: Could somebody please try this out? I'll accept the first answer by somebody who successfully tried it. Special thanks for testing under Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I would tentatively say "yes". The GPU is an NVIDIA. If you are connecting it to a monitor that correctly identifies 960 x 540 as a supported resolution then you should be able to set it in display properties. However, the NVIDIA Control Panel allows you to set custom resolutions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i rather doubt it, unless **[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)** can manage this resolution.

*PowerStrip is shareware ($19.95), try before you buy.*

There is a utility called **AsTray Plus**, which enables 900x540 on the Eee PC 701, but i don't think it will work with the Eee Box, it was written for the GMA 915 driver.

Answer (score -1):

Yes - Any machine that supports a resolution *should* support any resolution under that (monitor depending).

The monitor you use should send a signal telling the machine what its maximum resolution is, however, if Windows does not see this you can force a resolution:

To force a resolution that you cannot see in display settings

> - Launch Registry Editor
> - Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\GUID\0000` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video` (Depending on version of Windows)
>
> THE GUID will be on a video card basis, so you will have to change this on the correct one, if you have multiple cards and fail, try a different one. To look up the GUID (to get it right first time) look in Device Manager and go the card, go to advanced and look in the list. (It is another guide to tell you how to do this, if you want to know, let me know and I will write it).
>
> - Find both `DefautlSettings.XResolution` and `DefautlSettings.YResolution` and either convert a decimal number to hex and write it here, or change the value to decimal and just write 960 for `x` and 540 for `y` (hex 960 = 3c0 and 540 = 21c)
> - Reboot

Comment: Is that really the case? I would have thought if you set the resolution to 250*250 or other small incorrect-ratio values Bad Things would happen.

Comment: It may not look good if you have a low resolution, or the monitor may stretch it and it looks awful - but it doesn't mean that it isn't possible!